# Replace newline+4spaces with <br>

Tags: javascript, regex, dom, replace, expression

I want to replace all (newline+4spaces) of a string with `<br>` using `.replace()`.

What expression could I use to accomplish this?

I have only little knowledge of Javascript. The question that I asked might be too simple but for me it is difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
var str = "foo\n    bar\n    baz";
str = str.replace(/\n {4}/g,"<br>");
console.log(str); //foo<br>bar<br>baz
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pDDEp/1/)

Basically:
`/` = start regex
`\n` = newline
`{4}` = 4 spaces (note that there is a space in front of the `{4}` quantifier)
`/` = end regex
`g` = global flag, otherwise it would only replace the first match.

Comment: with newline i mean pressing "Enter" inside textarea then 4spaces indent.Can you give me expression to replace \r\n+4spaces.

Comment: Yes, test here: http://jsfiddle.net/pDDEp/2/. For `\r\n` just do that, `/\r\n {4}/g`

Comment: Test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pDDEp/4/), if you hit enter and then four spaces you'll see it converted into a `<br>`

Comment: Thanksfor help.yet i edited ur fiddle because it wasnt showing the result. Edited Fiddle:-http://jsfiddle.net/pDDEp/3/

Comment: @user2648239, the fiddle I posted above shows the result in the dom as well. The original one was putting the result in the console, do you know how to open up the console? If not, you should [**learn**](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers), it will help out immensely while doing web programming.

Comment: i know how to open console.I just wanted result on screen.

Answer (score 1):

If I think well this is what You are looking for:

```
var str = "somthing\n    something";
str = str.replace("\n    ","<br>");
```

Comment: OP asked 1 endline with 4 spaces